# Return value to variable in if else condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm on my way to build web with [TMDB](https://www.themoviedb.org/) webAPI, but i found out they use different variable for tv series and movies in trending section, tv use `name` and movie use `title` so there's will be *undefined* one. For newbie like me, i choose to use if else condition in function with return value, but it seems still not working.

```
const renderTrending = (results) => {
    const listTrendingElement = document.querySelector("#trendingNow");
    listTrendingElement.innerHTML = "";
    results.forEach(result => {
        const combine;
        function _combine(){
            if(result.name===undefined){
                return combine = result.title;
            } else {
                return combine = result.name;
            }
        }
        _combine();
        listTrendingElement.innerHTML += `
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="${posterTMDB}w185${result.poster_path}" alt="Poster">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">${combine}</h5>
                    <div>
                        <!-- <span class="genre">${result.genre_ids}</span>-->
                        <span class="media-type">${result.media_type}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        `;
    });
}
```

or maybe there's more effective way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the function with an oneliner:

```
const combine = result.name || result.title;
```

That way, if result.name returns a correct value, combine gets it; but if result.name is undefined, combine gets the value from result.title

Comment: This is dangerous : `||` checks for falsy values too, not only just `undefined`. The null coalescence operator `??` is a better choice (though not as widely supported). Otherwise use a ternary operator instead: `return result.name === undefined ? result.title : result.name`

Comment: @Terry the `name` field is supposed to be a string, so I personally agree with your instructing view, but the logical-or operator should fit the purpose without problems in this case.

Comment: @Terry for the same reason, you should patch your suggestion to prevent the `null` as well.

Comment: yes @MarioVernari this is specific for TMDB webAPI, not a general advice

Comment: thank you guys, i'll learn about logical operator.
have a nice day!